# why zmq_stream client need recv four times to get actual data?

Tags: stream, zeromq

the port 9070 is simple http server(tcp without zmq)
I had one questions:

1. why second recv is 0? where it come from?

thanks for help

```
void test_stream_to_tcp()
{
    uint8_t id [256];
    size_t id_size = 256;
    uint8_t buffer [256];
    void *ctx = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *client = zmq_socket (ctx, ZMQ_STREAM);
    int rc = 0;
    rc = zmq_connect (client, "tcp://localhost:9070");
    rc = zmq_getsockopt (client, ZMQ_IDENTITY, id, &id_size);
    rc = zmq_send (client, id, id_size, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
    rc = zmq_send (client, "GET /\n\n", 7, 0);
    assert (rc == 7);
    rc = zmq_recv (client, buffer, 256, 0);
    cout <<"first recv "<<  buffer << "rc = "<< rc<<endl;
    rc = zmq_recv (client, buffer, 256, 0);
    cout <<"second recv "<<  buffer<< "rc = "<< rc<<endl;
    rc = zmq_recv (client, buffer, 256, 0);
    cout <<"third recv "<<  buffer<< "rc = "<< rc<<endl;
    rc = zmq_recv (client, buffer, 256, 0);
    buffer[rc] = '\0';
    cout <<"forth  recv "<<  buffer<< "rc = "<< rc<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it, in zmq::stream_engine_t::plug
For raw sockets, send an initial 0-length message to the application so that it knows a peer has connected.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer.  I am having same issue.  I send data to this client, but receive 5 bytes, 0 bytes, 5 bytes, then real message.  Who has to send the 0-length message?